# how to download file from aws s3 bucket in nestjs

Tags: nestjs

My code is

```
AWS.config.update({accessKeyId:'my_access_key',secretAccessKey:'my_key'});
consts3 =new AWS.S3();
const option ={ 
 Bucket:'bucket_name',
 key:'key'
 };
 res.setHeader('Content-disposition','attachment; filename=abc.mp3');
 const filestream = createReadStream('hme/comp/documents/abc.mp3);
 filestream.pipe(res);
```

I want to download file from AWS s3 bucket in nestjs

Answer (score 4):

You can use `s3.getObject()` function for this purpose.

```
s3.getObject(
  { Bucket: "my-bucket", Key: "abc.mp3" },
  function (error, data) {
    if (error != null) {
      alert("Failed to retrieve an object: " + error);
    } else {
      alert("Loaded " + data.ContentLength + " bytes");
      // do something with data.Body
    }
  }
);
```

For streaming the file you can use this.

```
var options = {
    Bucket    : 'my-bucket',
    Key    : 'key',
};

res.attachment(fileKey);
var fileStream = s3.getObject(options).createReadStream();
fileStream.pipe(res);
```

Download to specific location with following code:

```
var file = require('fs').createWriteStream('your/download/path');
s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(file);
```

Comment: I want the downloaded file in my download folder how it can be done

Comment: Updated the answer with for downloading to specific location.

Comment: I want to  download  file  throught postman  in clients download folder

Comment: We can't decide where file would be downloaded in user's device. It will most likely be decided by postman.